# fwrite function not working

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a simple program that opens the content of a binary file into a buffer and the searches that buffer for the occurrence of string which is '+' characters. It seems like to does find these characters even though my algorithm is a little flaky. Once it finds them it changes the character to some other character. Then it writes the same buffer back to file. It does not work as I tried opening the file in a hex editor and could not find the new string with the new characters. The file that gets modified prints out the string that I am trying to modify using fread and fwrite.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

char XyZ[] = "++++++++++++++++++++++++++";    //26 count

int main()
{
    int error = 0;
    FILE * pFile;
    unsigned int lSize;
    char * buffer;
    size_t result;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    bool bfound = false;
    int count = 0;
    int startLocation = 0;

    pFile = fopen ( "E:\\DEVS\\Projects\\JustTesting\\FOpen\\Release\\Test.exe",   "rb+" );
    if (pFile==NULL) 
    {
        cout << "Unable to open Test.exe" << endl;   
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;      
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Successfully opened the file" << endl;

        // obtain file size:
        fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
        lSize = ftell (pFile);
        rewind (pFile);

        cout << "Number of file size is " << lSize << endl;

        // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
        buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
        if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

        // copy the file into the buffer:
        result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);

        cout << "Total bytes read into our buffer is " << result << endl;
        if (result != lSize) 
        {
            cout << "Error in reading the file" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            for(i = 0; i < lSize; i++)
            {
                if(buffer[i] == '+')    // '+'
                {
                    //cout << "Found first one" << endl;

                    startLocation = i;
                    //j = i + 1;
                    //cout << "Found the next one" << endl;
                    while(buffer[++i] == '+')
                    {
                        buffer[i] = '@';

                        cout << "Found the next one" << endl;
                        count++;
                    }
                }               
            }
            cout << "Found our string with count " << count << endl;

        }
        //for(int k = startLocation; k < startLocation + 5; k++)
        //  buffer[k] = '@';

        int value = fwrite (buffer , 1 , lSize , pFile );
        cout << "bytes written to file is :" << value << endl;
        fclose (pFile);
        free (buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about the exe file checksum?

Comment: No not really even though it may seem like it. I am actually trying to store a password inside a binary file instead of creating a plain text file. Certainly not hacking though. Thanks for the reply though. So if the password changes I would like to modify the binary file.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is your `while`:

```
while(buffer[++i] == '+')
```

So you've found your `+`, but in the `while` you first increase the position and then test whether the value is still `+`. That fails if you only have one `+` (and if you have several, the first is not overwritten). Instead, replace it with:

```
for ( ; (buffer[i] == '+') && (i < lSize) ; i++)
```

The next problem is that after `fread`, the file position is at the end. Your call to `fwrite` will thus append the modified buffer. To actually overwrite the file you first need to call `rewind(pFile);` again.

A final note on `fread`/`fwrite`: you read and write `lSize` items, each 1 byte in size. That's pretty slow (try it with a one megabyte file). Instead you likely want the opposite:

```
result = fread(buffer, lSize, 1, pFile);
```

Note that `result` will then merely have `1` on success. The same applies for `fwrite`.

Comment: Thanks DarkDust for the reply. I tried making the changes as you had kindly provided. But the file that contains the string that I attempt to modify crashes when you try to open or execute it. The code is quite simple for that file that I am testing this on. I tried posting it in this comment but could not figure out how to add the code blocks. Sorry.

Comment: I'm not surprised your modified program crashes as the code here replaces *every* instance of `+` without distinguishing whether it's a resource (your string) or some part of program instructions. You will need to make a check whether the `+` should really be overwritten (for example, first count the number of `+`, then only overwrite them when there's at least *n* number of `+`s). Note that you can always edit your question and put any additional info (like code) there.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you would be trying to write the modified contents at the end of the file. Besides, switching between read and write operations need certain function calls in between to switch the operation mode. Try adding

```
fseek( pFile, 0, SEEK_SET );
```

right before doing `fwrite`. Note that there may still be something wrong

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I would like to point out one strange thing that may be the issue. When I try search for the unmodified string in the test.exe file my search returns a total count of 132 ??? Even if I try another special character like the '!' or the '#' I get similar results (90 times when using the '!') on the number of matches. I don't understand why this is so ? There should not be that many ?

Comment: @user743543: Because there are lots of such characters in your file?

Comment: Thanks fo the reply. That is the sort of thing I don't understand because there are no such characters like that....or at least that many. However I think it can only be one other thing and that is the compiler/linker is using these characters in their compiling and linking. Lastly I just wanted to let everyone know that I forgo the idea to write to a binary file and instead went with writing to a text file to store certain data. Appreciate everyone's replies. Victor

Answer (score 0):

You open the file in `rb` (for reading), then write to it... I am not sure it will do what you want.

Comment: `"rb+"` is the same as `"r+b"` which means update both reading and writing.

Comment: @eudoxos: The `+` means it's also opened for writing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually the fopen function when used with rb+ opens a file for reading and writing both. I am quoting what the web page said "Open a file for update both reading and writing. The file must exist."